# Getting 95% emitting unnamed compat pluginError: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open

Tags: laravel, webpack

Whenever I do `npm run watch`, the first compilation works fine - but then after few compilations I'll eventually get this error:

> 95% emitting unnamed compat pluginError: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'D:\Laragon\www\erproj\public\js\app.js'

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix')

require('laravel-vue-lang/mix')

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')

mix.webpackConfig(
{
    module:
    {
        rules:
        [
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'eslint-loader',
                test: /\.(js|vue)?$/
            },
        ]
    }
})

mix.webpackConfig(
{
    module:
    {
        rules:
        [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use:
                [
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
                        options:
                        {
                            resources: './resources/sass/_*.scss'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
})

mix.webpackConfig(
{
    resolve:
    {
        alias:
        {
            '@': path.resolve('./resources/js'),
            '~': path.resolve('./resources/')
        }
    }
})

mix.webpackConfig(
{
    resolve:
    {
        alias:
        {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.js'
        }
    }
})

mix.webpackConfig(
{
    resolve:
    {
        alias:
        {
            '@lang': path.resolve('./resources/lang'),
        },
    },
    module:
    {
        rules:
        [
            {
                test: /resources[\\/]lang.+\.(php|json)$/,
                loader: 'laravel-localization-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
})
```

I've searched back and forth through google and found no solution that would work.
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1):

Try manually setting the path where all the assets are going to be compiled. You can do this by adding **mix.setPublicPath('public')**.

*Reference: https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/api#setpublicpathpath*